# Selfhost ServiceStack returns 404 after changing to AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase

Tags: servicestack

I've a selfhosted ServiceStack Service the apphost derives from **AppHostHttpListenerBase** . Because I will wneed some long running background tasks I wanted to thest out the **AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase**..

But after changing the base class, all requests (GET and POST) return a 404.
I can't find informations if I would have to make further changes?

Any hints?